# How to integrate a dashboard template in Vuejs to a Laravel 5.7 project

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack, core-ui

I have carefully followed CoreUI documentation guidelines for the topic's integration in vuejs development, this topic is designed with specific components for the integration in a vuejs environment. Said documentation specifies this commands for the installing, which I executed:

```js
git clone https://github.com/coreui/free-bootstrap-admin-template.git my-project
$ cd my-project
$ npm install.
```

Once executed, I copied the files from the folder /src into /resources of laravel projects, I also added:

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
 .js('resources/js/bootstrap.js', 'public/js')
  /*This is the mainjs on template /src*/
 .js('resources/js/main.js', 'public/js') /*This line is added*/
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');

mix.browserSync({
        proxy: 'http://localhost:8000'
    });
```

For the webpack to compile files' code /main.js which executes templates dependency

after executing “npm run watch” it generates the following error:

```js
ERROR in ./resources/js/router/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (68:31)

  66 | 
  67 | // Views
> 68 | const Dashboard        = () => import('@/views/Dashboard')
     |                                ^
  69 | 
  70 | const Colors           = () => import('@/views/theme/Colors')
  71 | const Typography       = () => import('@/views/theme/Typography')
```

after codifying the lines which contained

```
const Dashboard        = () => import('@/views/Dashboard')
```

and replace them with

```
import Dashboard        from 'resources/js/views/Dashboard.vue'
```

it generates another error:

```js
ERROR in ./resources/js/router/index.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (64:31)

  62 | 
  63 | Containers
> 64 | const DefaultContainer = () => import('resources/js/views/Dashboard.vue')
     |                                ^
  65 | 
  66 | 
  67 | // // Views
```

fiding documentation regarding vuejs templates implementation in laravel projects is very limited, which makes the implementation of this templates difficult. It would be very helpful if you comment suggestions o solutions regarding this.

Comment: try to replace `import` by `require('...')`

Comment: already did it, dont work

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
const Dashboard = () => System.import('@/views/Dashboard');
```

For some reason I've never gotten import to work without System in laravel based Vue project. This has fixed the problem for me. Also you could set:

```
const import = System.import();
```

At the top of your router so you won't have to modify all your imports.

Comment: throw an error in the word "import" in line "const import = System.import();"